# How do I show SQL with Play Framework?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, logging, playframework

I have a Play app that uses a database, and for debugging purposes I want to show the SQL that JPA uses. How can I do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In `application.conf`, you can turn showing SQL on uncommenting `jpa.debugSQL=true`. This will give you the prepared statement queries with question marks in them. Also, Play uses Hibernate, so you can also use Hibernate properties. These can be written in `application.conf` directly or in a separate `hibernate.properties` file residing in the `conf` folder of your Play application.

Comment: To show Hibernate code
hibernate.show_sql=true

If you want to see it nicely formatted add

hibernate.format_sql=true

Answer (score 6):

maybe this could also help

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/

it allows you so also see the sql binding parameters values...

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot. Perhaps you should include the relevant parts in your answer in case the site every goes down. I'd also recommend just using `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN` and `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace` to avoid a lot of log spam and print the SQL bindings only.