# How do I get the SQL Schema creation statements with Play! Framework?

Tags: schema, playframework

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672863/how-do-i-show-sql-with-play-framework) shows how to get Play! to show SQL statments. I followed on the accepted solution (`jpa.debugSQL=true`), but I still don't see the SQL statements that are used to create the tables themselves in the log.

How can I get those statements? (I'm currently using the in-memory database that comes with Play!, all default settings)

**Note** - if one of the SQL Schema statements goes wrong, it is displayed as an error in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in *application.conf* the value of your property:

```
application.log=INFO
```

It may be hiding the output.

If you are using a *log4j.properties* file you may want, as Zenklys says, check the appenders set up in there.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `log4j.properties` file. If you define a logger on debug level on hibernate package you should be able to get the SQL statements.