# Show JPA's SQL-Statements when using Play Framework 2

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0

I'm developing a web application using the Play Framework with JPA/Hibernate. For debugging purposes, it would be great to see the SQL statements used by JPA. There already is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672863/how-do-i-show-sql-with-play-framework) with the same question, but it is about Play 1 and the given solution does not work for me - it seems that `jpa.debugSQL=true` cannot be used in Play 2 (*No Persistence provider for EntityManager named true*).

Instead, I added the following to Play's application.conf:

```
db.default.logStatements=true
logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

I'm not sure if I need both lines, but at least the SQL statements are logged now.
But for large queries, Hibernate prints a ton of debug messages which make the already printed SQL statements disappear in my console window. I already tried to increase the buffer of the console window, but that didn't change much.

What do I have to do in order to inspect the statements in a comfortable way?

edit:

When setting `logger.org.hibernate` to `INFO`, I'm not getting any statements at all  (even with `db.default.logStatements=true`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try first with the config

```
db.default.logStatements=true
logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

Find out which class logs the statements (for example org.hibernate.xxx.StatementLogger).
Change back to INFO for org.hibernate and add a new line for the statement logger package:

```
logger.org.hibernate=INFO
logger.org.hibernate.xxx=DEBUG
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Finally, it's `logger.org.hibernate=INFO` + `logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`

Answer (score 3):

I was using Hibernate with HikariCp and above suggested changes were not working for me. Instead I used hibernate property to dump sql and it worked fine.

Add following lines in property section of your persistence.xml file.

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately don't know the way to do that in Hibernate, anyway in Ebean it's possible turn on and off logging directly in the code i.e. by:

```
Ebean.getServer(null).getAdminLogging().setDebugGeneratedSql(true);
```

or

```
Ebean.getServer(null).getAdminLogging().setDebugGeneratedSql(false);
```

On the quite other hand if Hibernate prints a ***ton of debug messages*** it may indicate that you should consider optimizing your queries, i.e. if you getting list of 100 records with lazy loaded relations - ORM needs to perform additional queries for missing data and instead one query with join(s) it performs `n` * relations, so it can be real *`performance killer`*.

Comment: Thanks. It is already a single query with a single result-entity but with some fetch joins going on in order to eagerly load some one-to-many relationships.

Comment: Yes I'm talking exactly about this _eagerly load_, try to optimize ypur query, or perform second query and join data manually, otherwise when you'll go to production i.e. to Heroku you can be massively surprised (in bad meaning of these words)